# Slicing array by using another array as the slice indices along axis

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Say I have an array that looks like the following:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]]
```

And I have another array `slicer = [1,3,2]`. I want to apply these values as the slice index over axis 0 measure along axis 1.

This doesn't work (and in fact contains no way of specifying that the along part is axis 1 in an ndarray) but suppose I tried `arr[:slicer, :]`

I would hope to obtain,

```
out = [[1,   2,   3],
       [nan, 5,   6],
       [nan, 8, nan]]
```

which is the combination of applying the slice `arr[:1, :]`, `arr[:3, :]`, `arr[:2, :]` and then selecting from those the 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns respectively and reassembling into the array above, dropping missing values.

I want to avoid loops and trying to find a fast vectorised solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this operation you need to first generate a boolean index mask that marks all fields you want to set to `nan`. Broadcasting makes it easy to perform an "outer comparison" that yields the desired result

```
slicer = numpy.asarray([1, 3, 2])
mask = numpy.arange(3)[:, None] >= slicer
mask
# array([[False, False, False],
#        [ True, False, False],
#        [ True, False,  True]])
```

You can then simply use this mask to index `data`

```
data = numpy.arange(1, 10, dtype=float).reshape(3, 3)
data[mask] = numpy.nan
data
# array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
#        [nan,  5.,  6.],
#        [nan,  8., nan]])
```

Comment: marvellous result, in record time. Thanks.