# How to select elements in numpy array with given starting point indices

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have a matrix like this:

```
In [2]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

and a starting point index array:

```
In [4]: idx = np.array([1, 2, 0])

In [5]: idx
Out[5]: array([1, 2, 0])
```

Are there any vectorized ways to do such things:

```
for i in range(3):
    # The following are some usecases
    a[i, idx[i]:] = 0
    a[i, idx[i]-1:] = 0
    a[i, :idx[i]] = 0
    a[i, idx[i]:idx[i]+2] = 0
```

Edit: expected output:

```
array([[ 0,  x,  x,  x],
       [ 4,  5,  x,  x],
       [ x,  x,  x,  x]])
```

x is placeholder indicating what I'd like to select.

Comment: please provide output which you are looking for.

Comment: Your code returns `a` as all zeros. Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243609/slicing-array-by-using-another-array-as-the-slice-indices-along-axis/51244071#51244071)?

Comment: @Brenlla My requirement is similar to what you provided, but that only applies to square matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [aproach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51244071/6091318) works for rectangular matrices too. Create a boolean mask trough broadcasting:

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
idx = np.array([1, 2, 0])
mask=np.arange(a.shape[1]) >= idx[:,None]
mask
#array([[False,  True,  True,  True],
#       [False, False,  True,  True],
#       [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Make your *placeholder* `-1`, for example, and set the values of `a` where `mask` is true equal to that placeholder:

```
x = -1
a[mask] = x
a
#array([[ 0, -1, -1, -1],
#       [ 4,  5, -1, -1],
#      [-1, -1, -1, -1]])
```

Comment: Thanks, works as expected, didn't realize arange should be on dim 1

Answer (score 0):

An expected, exact, output is not provided. So, I think the followings may help you in general.

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> row = np.array([0, 1, 2])
>>> col = np.array([1, 2, 0])
>>> a[row, col]
array([1, 6, 8])
```

You can set the `row` and `col`s of `a` to an value:

```
>>> a[row, col] = 0
>>> a
array([[ 0,  0,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  0,  7],
       [ 0,  9, 10, 11]])
```