# on a numpy 2D array - how to set last N array elements in each row to zero when N changes over rows

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Say, I have a 2D numpy array consists of 20 elements, for example:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 15, 7],[9, 11, 17, 19],[5, 7, 5, 8],[19, 4, 1, 45],[10, 7, 14, 8]])
```

and an additional array:

```
to_zero = np.array([0, 2, 1, 3, 2])
```

now, for each row `i` I would like to make the last `to_zero[i]` elements equal to zero, so eventually we will get the following result:

```
res = np.array([[1, 2, 15, 7],[9, 11, 0, 0],[5, 7, 5, 0],[19, 0, 0, 0],[10, 7, 0, 0]])
```

I would like to do this operation on a very big array. 
Is there any way to do this operation vectorized, with no loops, and no auxiliary arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select elements in numpy array with given starting point indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441319/how-to-select-elements-in-numpy-array-with-given-starting-point-indices)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `broadcasted-comparison` to get a mask of those trailing ones and then mask the input -

```
In [63]: r = np.arange(arr.shape[1])[::-1]

In [66]: mask = to_zero[:,None]>r

In [69]: mask # mask of trailing places to be reset in input
Out[69]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True]])

In [67]: arr[mask] = 0

In [68]: arr
Out[68]: 
array([[ 1,  2, 15,  7],
       [ 9, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  7,  5,  0],
       [19,  0,  0,  0],
       [10,  7,  0,  0]])
```

Alternative to  getting `r` would be with `np.arange(arr.shape[1]-1,-1,-1)`.

Alternative to get the final output with element-wise multiplication : `arr*~mask`.

Or construct the *flipped-mask* with the *flipped-comparison* and then multiply -

```
In [75]: arr*(to_zero[:,None]<=np.arange(arr.shape[1]-1,-1,-1))
Out[75]: 
array([[ 1,  2, 15,  7],
       [ 9, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  7,  5,  0],
       [19,  0,  0,  0],
       [10,  7,  0,  0]])
```

For large arrays, leverage multi-cores with `numexpr` -

```
In [78]: import numexpr as ne

In [79]: ne.evaluate('arr*mask',{'mask':to_zero[:,None]<=np.arange(arr.shape[1]-1,-1,-1)})
Out[79]: 
array([[ 1,  2, 15,  7],
       [ 9, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  7,  5,  0],
       [19,  0,  0,  0],
       [10,  7,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this operation vectorized, with no **auxiliary arrays** as noted in the question?

Comment: @aviyaChe Basically you are asking for a builtin and sadly there isn't any in NumPy. Also, we are constructing a mask/boolean array that occupies 1/8th of an int array on unix systems.

Comment: Even though the selection for a given row is a slice, the selection for the whole array requires some form of advanced indexing, identifying each element.  That's what the mask does.